# Inappropriate migration to SF?

Tags: discussion, migration

This question was migrated to SF a bit ago:

> [Suspicious redirection to russian pages. Is government spying us?](https://superuser.com/questions/269551/suspicious-redirection-to-russian-pages-is-government-spying-us?noredirect=1)

After being received by us, it was quickly closed as being off-topic (I would have voted to migrate back to SU, but it appears that it's not possible to migrate a question back to a site it was just migrated from) which is too bad as I thought it was a fairly decent question. It seemed clear to us that this question was solidly in the realm of SU.

I'd like to understand what in that question made it seem appropriate to migrate. The question was clearly written from the perspective of an individual user (and friend), and the concept of IP Geolocation (and issues therein) are fairly well-known

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP flagged his own question and asked to have it move to SF, as he viewed it as off-topic for SU.  I had seen the question before it was flagged, and thought it seemed fine for SU... My apologies for not checking more closely whether or not this was on-topic for SF.

If you would delete the question on your end (or flag for a mod to delete), then I will reopen on SU, and add a note to the OP that it does not belong on SF and needs to stay at SU.  Thanks!

Comment: @studiohack - Thanks for the answer. So then you knew it was on-topic for SU, but migrated anyway? Seems like that would have been a good opportunity to educate the OP why his question should *not* be migrated.

Comment: @ErikA: it seemed pretty borderline, like it could fit at either place, as it was a question about networking and IP Geolocation, etc. and there seems to be some overlap in the networking areas between SU and SF...

Comment: @studiohack - fair enough. I think that while the topic itself may be appropriate for SF, the user himself was clearly not a Server/Network professional, thereby making it off-topic for SF. I now see that you've re-opened his question on SU, so I'll go ahead and re-post my answer from SF there. Thanks!

Comment: and btw @ErikA: thanks for posting this on Meta and letting me know about this (instead of letting it go or just "stuffing it"), I'm still learning in some ways as a mod and appreciate the feedback...migrating to other sites is tricky for me sometimes.

Comment: @studiohack You're welcome. We cause our fair share of mis-migrated questions on SF as well, and always appreciate constructive criticism in those instances as well.

Comment: @ErikA cheers! :)

Comment: @Studiohack - I often drop into a chat room of a site I'm thinking of flagging for mod-migration just to check. Queries like this are always welcome in The Comms Room

Comment: I know that SF has migrated stuff to SU before that probably shouldn't have happened and that both sites have been victims of "drive by question dumping" by SO - makes you wonder if there's some way of improving this aspect of the sites.

Comment: @Robert - I have thought for quite some time that it would be beneficial if the community had some way of reversing unilateral migrations. Perhaps to reverse, the question would need to get 7 or 10 "move back" votes instead of the normal 5 that migration requires.

Comment: @ErikA - I think the issue gets ignored because stack overflow isn't usually the **victim** of bad migrations, so when any of us from the other sites post there about the issue they don't understand the pain it can cause. Anyway, while I don't claim to have all the answers, this was my suggestion on meta.stackoverflow: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84839/should-moving-offtopic-questions-to-other-stack-exchange-sites-cost-reputation

Comment: @Robert - I would agree on your reasoning for this being ignored. I think either of these solutions would be quite helpful.